# How to find or resolve this DBNull in asp.net c# when using Mysql as database

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I have this problem using ASP.Net MVC3 (c#) and Mysql 5.5 as database for my final year project. The problem is that I have just added my database to my project and using server explorer, I used "Add Connection" and got a list of tables. But when I right click on any table and do a `Refresh` it shows me an error box saying **"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Dbnull' to 'System.string' "**.

Please note that I haven't wrote a single line of code yet.

- What is this DbNull?
- How can I come out of this and start coding?

Here is the image ..
[image]

Here's how I created the table:

```
CREATE TABLE admintable
( 
emailid varchar(45) NOT NULL Primary Key, 
password varchar(45) NOT NULL);
```

Comment: what don't you use a int or unique identifier as a primary key?

Comment: Hi @ePezhman thats not the issue thats a sample table but even if i use a table with int as primary key that is leading me same result...

Comment: anyway follow this one, it helped me http://kalanaonline.blogspot.nl/2011/01/connecting-mysql-to-visual-studio-2010.html